# Why the key of the previous child in order is returned on ChildEventListener()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the following POC, we have the `addChildEventListener` with all the `@Override` methods accepting as second argument the "String s" which is the key of the previous child.

Is there any specific reason for this? I guess there is some design pattern where knowing the key of the previous child makes things easier?

```
Query recentPostsQuery = mDatabase.child("Posts").limitToFirst(100);

    recentPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Log.d("test", dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.d("test", dataSnapshot.child("Title").toString());
            Log.d("test", s);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm more curious why onChildRemoved _doesn't_ provide the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the initial children of your query, `onChildAdded` will be called in the order that you have requested the children. In your snippet that means its called for incremental keys.

But later a child might be added somewhere between two existing nodes. In that case `onChildAdded` would fire and you'd use the `String previousKey` to determine where to insert it in your views.